# Order of ActorContext changes

Tags: akka, actor

I noticed that actor at first sent message about state change and later really has been changed this state. It's correct?

```
class MyActor extends Actor {
  def receive = idle(Set.empty)

  def idle(isInSet: Set[String]): Receive = {
    case Add(key) =>
      // sending the result as a message back to our actor
      validate(key).map(Validated(key, _)).pipeTo(self)

      // waiting for validation
      context.become(waitForValidation(isInSet, sender()))
  }

  def waitForValidation(set: Set[String], source: ActorRef): Receive = {
    case Validated(key, isValid) =>
      val newSet = if (isValid) set + key else set
      // sending acknowledgement of completion
      source ! Continue
```

Here occurs sending notification

```
      // go back to idle, accepting new requests
      context.become(idle(newSet))
```

and later changed state

```
    case Add(key) =>
      sender() ! Rejected
  }

  def validate(key: String): Future[Boolean] = ???
}

// Messages

case class Add(key: String)
case class Validated(key: String, isValid: Boolean)
case object Continue
case object Rejected
```

Answer (score 0):

You should probably consider moving become() before pipeTo(self) if you want the actor to receive the message in the waitForValidation state:

```
context.become(waitForValidation(isInSet, sender()))
validate(key).map(Validated(key, _)).pipeTo(self)
```

I agree that piping the message will put it in the queue, and by the time the object gets to processing it the object should be in the new state, but most of the examples I have seen call the become before piping just to be on the safe side.